# tensorflow lite c library build

Tags: tensorflow, build

I followed the instructions to build the tensorflow lite c library described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake, and got:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:

```
common.c
```

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
.hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: tensorflowlite_c

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, cmake version 3.23.1

Comment: It looks like that file has been renamed to common.cc, but CMakeLists.txt hasn't been updated yet...

Comment: I copied common.cc to common.c and everything compiled correctly. However, the resultant library produced the same feature vector for a number of different inputs. I therefore suspect that something additional is required.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/wangjia184/27d02d50906641b7463b67107e1622ba